# How increase scanning resolution in for canon Lide 220 scanner in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: display-resolution, scanner

I am using Canon Lide220 scanner, and simple scan is used for scanner, but the resolution is poor. how i can increase the scanning resolution? can i use any other scanning software in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Did you try increasing the resolution through `Preferences`?

Comment: Additional information: lide 220 is listed as having complete SANE support in http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a Canon LIDE210 so I presume this is the same (the [only difference I could find](http://www.imaging-resource.com/news/2014/07/09/canons-latest-canoscan-lide-scanners-will-digitize-your-shoebox-of-photos-w) between the 210 and 220 is the renaming of one button and corresponding change in the Windows-only software). Open Simple Scan and click on the Document menu then go to Preferences. There you can set Text and Photo DPI separately as well as change some other options for scanning.